# Некорректный вывод после импорта базы данных MySQL

Tags: кодировка, mysql

*Здравствуйте!*

В общем, импортирую базы данных MySql с локальной машины на сервер. Импортировались отлично, все русскими буквами, как на локалке, НО на странице все выводится ЗНАКАМИ ВОПРОСА! Если вводить в базу данных данные с сайта, загруженного на сервер то они добавляются в виде Р’С‹РІРѕРґ а выводят как нужно! Помогите сделать так **чтобы в базе данных все было на русском и также выводилось на веб страницу**!

*Заранее огромное спасибо!*

Comment: Какая у вас кодировка в базе данных? И какая кодировка при печати html страницы?

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте добавить в <head> страницы:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

После подключения к БД установите кодировку с помощью след. запроса

```
$query = 'SET CHARSET utf8';        
$db->query ( $query );
```

Пошлите с помощью ф-и header() следующие заголовок для сервера:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
```

Если используете не utf8, исправьте на свою. Используйте обязательно все приведенное выше для своего сайта ( по отдельности может не работать, проверено на практике, сам когда-то столкнулся с крякозябрами после вывода из БД)